# Producing a list of permutations from an array

Tags: python, algorithm

This is probably straightforward but I'm new to this sort of programming and struggling to wrap my head around what I need to do.

I'm trying to build a list of filters to apply to an image. I have seven filters I can apply and each filter can either be `0` or `1` (on or off). The filters are:

```
filters = [
    'Exposure',
    'Noise',
    'Pressure',
    'XQ Mix',
    'Invert',
    'Desaturate',
    'Equalise'
]
```

What I want to produce is every possible permutation of these filters in their states. There should be 128 possible permutations (2^7) but when I run the following code I get 5080 permutations:

```
perms = permutations(filters)
perm_count = 0
for p in perms:
    print(p)
    perm_count = perm_count + 1

print str(perm_count) + ' total permutations'
```

I'm likely using the wrong method – all this is doing is shuffling the sequence of filters, which I don't care about.

I tried updating the filter list to have two items for each filter, eg. `['Exposure0', 'Exposure1']` etc, but running `combinations(filters, 7)` against this gives me duplicate values (eg. both on and off states in the same list).

I'm struggling here – can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction for approaching something like this? Looking in the docs, something like `product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy` seems along the right lines but I still can't wrap my head around it. Help appreciated.

Comment: Note: you can use `len(list(...))`. Oh, and explicitly state `itertools` plz.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I tried using `len(list(...))` initially (and again just now to check) and it returns 0 – that was why I added the counter.

Comment: That's.. how should I say it... *interesting*... works here.

Comment: ... what? Because that code didn't work on my machine?

Comment: Your machine isn't special. It works there too. Feel free to post a separate question ;)

Comment: What would you do if someone says 2+2 is 5? Why is this unfriendly or passive-aggressive?

Comment: The downvote icon for the question says "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Me replying here about what an (unrelated) method call does has no bearing on my question. You should read this article, maybe: https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: I know that article. Let me ask you something: does my profile suggest I like what's going on here? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for as far as I understand is called a powerset.
Here are some implementations for this method:
[Getting the subsets of a set in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988695/getting-the-subsets-of-a-set-in-python)

Comment: Thank you – this was exactly what I wanted – effectively the missing items in the set are the "off" values and I can work out my filters. Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `permutations` the wrong way. Look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> permutations('ABCD', 2)
AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
```

You are just mixing your `filters` values and creating all the possibilities, which is 7! = 5040.

What you want is the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of `(0, 1)` seven times.

```
>>> p = product((0, 1), repeat=7)
>>> print(len(p))
128
# [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), ...]
```

Comment: Thank you – have already accepted the other answer (because it gives me the actual list of "on" filters, whereas here I'd still need to associate the list of 0/1s with the filter sequence again. Thanks though, I've learned something about `itertools` today.

Comment: @MattAndrews Sure, the main thing is that you have resolved your issue, I hope you better understand how to use `product()` and `permutations()` now.